# How to use loading in Interceptor in Angular V 17

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

I'm tryinh to use interceptor in the new version angular 17

```
export const loadingInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next,) => {
const loadingService = inject(LoadingService);
loadingService.show();
return next(req).pipe(
 finalize(() => {
  loadingService.hide();
    })
  );
};
```

ERROR TypeError: next is not a function

what is the correct way to do it in the new version

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'handle' function => 'next.handle(req)'

```
export const loadingInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next,) => {
const loadingService = inject(LoadingService);
loadingService.show();
return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => loadingService.hide()));
};
```

Comment: Property 'handle' does not exist on type 'HttpHandlerFn'  not found

Comment: I've try add (req, next: HttpHandlerFn)  but not work

Comment: Did you properly declare the interceptor in the AppModule ?
see: https://itnext.io/migrate-angular-interceptors-to-function-based-interceptors-90bd433e0c2a

Comment: I called it in app.config 
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideAnimations(), 
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([autenticacaoInterceptor])),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([loadingInterceptor])),
  ]
};